# Changes from repository lost on git pull

Tags: git, github, merge

I've had a couple issues at work where changes someone else made in the repository are lost when I pull. I can't figure out why their work, which was committed and pushed, is lost when I pull and then push my commits after merging. Here is my work flow:

1. Add files to staging
2. Commit the changed files
3. Pull from remote repository
4. Fix any merge conflicts if necessary
5. Push my commit(s) to the remote repository

When I do this, the work done in someone else's last commit will be gone. I've been trying to figure out why this is happening and what I could be doing wrong. After all my research, I can't figure out what is wrong with my work flow. Is there a reason, maybe in the merge, for the last commit someone else pushed getting lost? The merge after pulling is done automatically.

Comment: What makes you think their work is gone?

Comment: Could you clarify gone? Do you mean the commits are no longer present in `git log` or the lines of code are absent from files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **fetch** instead of **pull** .. it will solve the problem

1. Add files to staging
2. Commit the changed files.
3. **Fetch from remote repository**
4. **Merge the local repo changes with your remote repo**
5. Fix any merge conflicts if necessary
6. Push my commit(s) to the remote repository

Here is the link which will give deeper look
http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/

Comment: There's a step 3.5 - Merge.  But at that point, Steps 3 + 3.5 are equivalent to just doing a pull.

Comment: Thanks buddy .. I miss read 4 point as merging + removing conflicts

Comment: This article helped me a lot. Thank you.